# Looping through Amazon MWS orders API by using NextToken PHP

Tags: php, api, loops, foreach, amazon-mws

I am making a curl request to Amazon MWS orders API to get ListOrders then I loop through the xml response using foreach loop and prints the response in html table.

But as per Amazon MWS Orders API it only returns 100 results in one request and to get more results I need to make another curl request by using other parameter  NextToken that I got from the last response of previous request which then will return next 100 orders and so on until there is no more NextToken available.

So my question is how can I iterate to the new response of NextToken request again and again and print the response in html table until there is no more NextToken available?

Comment: Try using Amazon's Report API with report type "_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_" to get order data and you won't have to look for next token.

Comment: https://github.com/keyur-padalia/Amazon-API-Helper-Class/blob/master/AmazonAPIs/amazon_report_helper.class.inc

Comment: Thanks @Keyur I got the flat file but I have few questions - 1. How to manipulate this flat file response. Suppose I want to store in mysql database? 2. I can't select the time frames means from when to when this report is? 3. Is this real time?

Answer (score 1):

**Report response is also avilable in XML format**

For those who is still struggling and want an easy way to get orders data. Please use Amazon MWS Reports API and request a report using -

**ReportType:**_GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_

For more info see 
https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to convert the report's csv response to an array for saving into database.

```
$report_listing = explode("\n", $report_data["report_data"]);
$orders_list = '';

$i = 0;
$headers = '';
// Building an Associative array of CSV report
foreach($report_listing as $listing)
{
    if($i == 0)
    {
        $headers = explode("\t", trim($listing));
    }
    else
    {
        $csv_data = explode("\t", $listing);
        if(!isset($csv_data[1]))
            continue;
        foreach($headers as $key => $index)
        {
            $orders_list[$i - 1][$index] = $csv_data[$key];
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

$new_order = array();

// Combining order items into one order array
foreach($orders_list as $orders)
{
    $new_order[$orders['amazon-order-id']][] = $orders;
}
```

Comment: @OrientDevelopers If it works, please rate my answer or accept my answer

Comment: actually I want real time orders data means whenever there is an order my app should fetch data in background and store in db. Will this flat file help me to achieve the same?

Comment: And from when to when it gives the report?

Comment: You can request the report by last how many days you want. The only down side if this reports takes about 3-4 minutes to generate. So I think the best option is to use order's api

Comment: but how can I keep looping in nexttoken request/response...our company gets more that 2000 orders per day....Please give some help currently I can only send one request for nexttoken...so i am getting 200 orders 100 by making ListOrders request and next 100 by nexttoken request.

Comment: Using do while loop

Comment: I just added Amazon Order's API Helper class. It might help you. https://github.com/keyur-padalia/Amazon-API-Helper-Class/blob/master/AmazonAPIs/amazon_orders_helper.class.inc

Comment: Hi @Keyur I resumed this project and want to use your helper class can you please provide the installation guide for your class in order to work perfectly.Also update your github README where it still says Orders API (not yet in this repository)

Comment: Hi @OrientDevelopers the README.md gives you all setup instructions. if you stuck anywhere then let me know